# Saving GWT form data into different application

Tags: google-app-engine, gwt

I have a GWT application which has form. If user enters data and submit i have to store the data into google datastore and also an JSP application which is running on tomcat server. I found this is done through Task in GAE [GAE Push](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/taskqueue/overview-push) Task from this i am calling a servlet in my gwt application and in that servlet [URL fetch](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/urlfetch/overview) There i have to code to send data to another application and call the servlet to insert data. Can anyone give me how to do it(By a simple example). Is this a correct approach or any other way to do this correctly?

Comment: Well you are going in right direction, you need to submit data to servlet from your GWT form and from there you can use URLFetch APIs of GAE to submit data to whichever URL you need to submit.

Comment: I have to pass some data to the second application i am sending it in by put the data in request object. I don't know how to pass request object to another aplication.

Answer (score 0):

I have done it successfully added a push queue task in server side and called a servlet from there which is registered in guice. then in that servlet i called the fallowing lines

Task queue code

```
Queue queue = QueueFactory.getDefaultQueue();
            queue.addAsync(TaskOptions.Builder.withUrl("/userServlet").method(Method.GET).param("userName", userName).param("pwd", pwd).param("mail",mail));
```

and userservlet has fallowing code to connect to theother application

```
final String url_Name = "http://xxxxxxxx.com/AddUserServlet";

         //final String url_Name = "http://localhost:8181/jos-webapp-1.2.1/AddUserServlet";

         URLFetchService fetcher = URLFetchServiceFactory.getURLFetchService();
         HTTPRequest request = null;
         HTTPResponse response= null;
         try{


             URL url = new URL(url_Name);

             request = new HTTPRequest(url, HTTPMethod.POST);

             String body = "userName="+uName+"&pwd="+pwd+"email"+email;
             request.setPayload(body.getBytes());

             response = fetcher.fetch(request);

         }catch(Exception ex){
             ex.printStackTrace();
         }
```

In my JOIDS(second application) I wrote a servlet(AdduserServlet) and used someget the data. Any better solution than this will be accepted