# AOP Advice is not triggering in JOIDS application

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-aop

In my application i try to connect to different application and save data. In that part i succeeded to save that data. But the problem is when i save email it has to trigger an email advice predefined. but it is not happening. This is my code to connect explained in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16642558/saving-gwt-form-data-into-different-application) and my code in servlet on other application is.

```
ApplicationContext context = WebApplicationContextUtils.getRequiredWebApplicationContext(getServletContext());

String uname = request.getParameter("userName");
String pwd = request.getParameter("pwd");
String email = request.getParameter("email");

userDao.insertUser(user);
passDao.insertPassword(password);

User u1 =userDao.getUser(domain, uname);

Email command = new Email();

command.setCreationDate(new Date());
command.setAddress(email);
command.setUser(u1);
command.setLocale(new Locale("en","US"));

log.debug("Upto user adding data");

JosService josService = (JosService)context.getBean("josService");

try {
    log.debug("before adding email data");
    josService.insertEmail(u1,command);
    log.debug("After adding email data");
} catch (Exception e) {
    log.error("Setting and sending email address is failed");
    e.printStackTrace();
}

log.debug("Data saved succesfully");
response.setStatus(200);
```

In my applicationcontext.xml has the defined advice like this

```
<!-- ================ ADVISOR DEFINITIONS ================ -->
<bean id="emailAdvisor" class="org.springframework.aop.support.RegexpMethodPointcutAdvisor">
    <property name="advice">
        <ref local="insertEmailAfterReturningAdvice" />
    </property>
    <property name="pattern">
        <value>.*insertEmail</value>
    </property>
</bean>

<!-- ================ ADVICE DEFINITIONS ================ -->
<bean id="insertEmailAfterReturningAdvice" class="cn.net.openid.jos.service.InsertEmailAfterReturningAdvice">
    <constructor-arg>
        <ref local="emailConfirmationInfoSendTaskExecutor" />
    </constructor-arg>
</bean>

<bean id="emailConfirmationInfoSendTaskExecutor" class="cn.net.openid.jos.service.EmailConfirmationInfoSendTaskExecutor">
    <constructor-arg ref="taskExecutor" />
    <property name="mailSender" ref="mailSender" />
    <property name="passwordDao" ref="passwordDao" />
</bean>
```

Comment: I solved the problem. It's my mistake i have to set domain in my custom servlet (to access it in advice class) i debugged though the program. And domain got null in Email advice. Due to no logs in Advice i don't get any errors before. Problem solved....